# Searching specific indexes in arrays for specific numbers

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, indexing

Hi there is there a way to check specific integer array indexes for specific numbers in C#; for example what I would love to have worked would be:

```
    if(si[6] || si[7] || si[8] == 3)
     {
      MessageBox.Show("3 detected")
     }
    else
    {
     continue();
    {
```

Obviously this doesn't work. Is there a clean way to do this? Thank you for looking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var indexes = new int[] {6, 7, 8};
if (indexes.Any(i => si[i] == 3))
{
    MessageBox.Show("3 detected")
}
```

Comment: And if there are different values (besides 3) with different indices then a `Dictionary<int, int[]>` would work.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest is to make three separate checks:

```
if (si[6] == 3 || si[7] == 3 || si[8] == 3)
```

Comment: Consider performing bounds checking first as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this a bit neater using a method with a params:

```
public static bool HasValue(int value, params int[] itemsToCheck)
{
    bool valueDetected = false;
    foreach(var item in itemsToCheck)
    {
        valueDetected |= item == value;
    }

    return valueDetected;
}
```

Then you could just call it like this:

```
if (HasValue(3, si[6], si[7], si[8]))
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array.IndexOf function to find the index of the integer. If array has the integer then it will return the index else it will return -1.

Like this
            int[] a = new int[] { 1, 2 };
            int c = Array.IndexOf(a, 2);

Comment: he wants to search the data at specific `index` not in the entire array